# $A$, $B$ are abelian normal in $D_4$ and their intersection is trivial but $AB$ is not abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

[If $H$ and $K$ are abelian normal subgroups of a group then prove $HK$ is abelian.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1913066/168676)

When i saw post in above link, which says that:

> If $H$, $K$ are abelian normal subgroups of a group and $H\cap
> K=\{e\}$ then $HK$ is abelian.

An example cames to my mind that, If we consider $G=D_4$ that is Group of symmetries of square and $A=\{R_0, R_{180°}, H, V\}$,  $B=\{R_0, R_{180°}, D, D'\}$.

( where, $R_0=$ rotation by 0°, $R_{180°}=$ rotation by 180°, $H=$ reflection about horizontal axis, $V=$ reflection about vertical axis, $D=$ reflection about main diagonal, $D'=$reflection about other diagonal.)

Then $A\cap B=\{R_0\}$ and as $|A|=|B|=4$ hence they are Abelian. Further as, $|G:A|=2, |G:B|=2$ we have $A,B$ are normal subgroups of $G$. But $AB=G=D_4$ **which is not abelian!**

Hence this contradicts above result( Am i wrong?) Please help..

Comment: Sorry i made mistakes. $A\cap B=\{R_0, R_{180°}\}≠\{R_0\}$ and hence example doesn't contradicts results in post.

Comment: No you are not wrong. The statement that you are required to prove  in the first line of your post is false.

Comment: @DerekHolt sir, means the statement/result in given link is false? I think no it is not false.

Comment: The first sentence in your post above is: "If  and  are abelian normal subgroups of a group then prove  is abelian." That statement (I mean what you are asked to prove) is false.  You were correct in saying that the subgroups $A$ and $B$ of $D_4$ provide a counterexample. If you make the additional assumption that $H \cap K = \{e\}$, then it is correct, but the point is the statement in the first line of your post does NOTmake that assumption. This is all very strange, because I am telling you that you were right, and now you are telling me that I am wrong!

Comment: @DerekHolt: The original post linked-to had a title that omits the hypothesis $H\cap K=\{e\}$, but which included that hypothesis in the body of the post, thus leading to the confusion.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes I realize that now, thanks!